# cannot run WSL2 as any user but administrator

Tags: windows, wsl2

I recentrly installed WSL2 and ubuntu on a freshly installed Windows 20H2 machine, where at first the user didn't have high permissions and when I used `run as administrator` it asked for the explicit administrator password.
After installing ubuntu 18.04 for WSL2 everything worked when ran as the other user.

Then I added the regular user to the admin group, so it would have the run as admin option.
But when I tried to run `wsl.exe` it would say there are no distributions installed, and when I tried to run ubuntu explicitly it says the `Virtual  Machine Platform` feature is not enabled (error 0x80370102).
And again when running cmd `as different user` and using **the built-in administrator** everything works fine, meaning there is no virtualization problem, or one of the other suggestions I found when searching the error online

I can't find any permissions administrator has and the regular user doesn't, what can be the issue?

Comment: WSL distributions are per-user. Did you install a WSL distribution with your regular user yet?

Comment: yes, when running the distribution for the first time as the user it says the virtual machine platform is not enabled and aborts the installation

Comment: If you don’t have Virtual  Machine Platform installed then your WSL instances cannot be WSL2 instances.  You will want to enable the feature before continuing to diagnose your other issue

Comment: But I do have virtual machine platform installed, as I said it works fine when running as the built-in administrator but doesn't when using the other user

Comment: Well, I reinstalled Windows and for some unknown version it solved it :\

Comment: Would have been interesting to know the "why" on this one, but good to hear you got it fixed, at least.  You might want to request that a mod close the question, or you can delete it yourself, of course.  If it stays open, every so often (sometimes years later) the Stack "community" bot will come along and bump it to the top of the queue to see if anyone has new info.

Comment: I have no idea why it happened and what solved it (but making sure the regular user runs wsl for the first time before administrator..), should I delete the question or leave it open?